# RunTime Error: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 (Mismatch in shape)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am trying to implement a VAE, and i am having trouble calculating the gradient for the model. I believe this is happening in the decoder. The exact error message is **Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [10, 32] but expected shape compatible with [10, 1024]**. Here is the decoder model.

```
class decoderNW(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(decoderNW,self).__init__()

        channels = 32
        kernelSize = 4
        padding = (2,0)
        stride = (2,2)
        outputpadding = (1,0)

        self.FC1 = nn.Linear(channels, 1024)

        self.FC2 = nn.Linear(channels, 10656)

        self.deConv3x301 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels, 64, kernel_size=kernelSize, stride=stride, output_padding=outputpadding)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.deConv3x301.weight)

        self.deConv3x302 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 128, kernel_size=kernelSize, stride=stride, output_padding=outputpadding)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.deConv3x302.weight)

        self.deConv3x303 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=kernelSize, stride=stride, output_padding=outputpadding)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.deConv3x303.weight)

        self.deConv3x304 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, kernel_size=kernelSize, stride=stride)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.deConv3x304.weight)

        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
 


        self.ReLU = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self,x):

        x = self.FC1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)
        # Shape of x => 10x1024

        x = self.FC2(x)

        # Shape of x => 10x10656
        # Reshape x as 10x8x42x75
        x = x.view(x.size(0),32,9,37)

        x = self.deConv3x301(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)

        x = self.deConv3x302(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)

        x = self.deConv3x303(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = self.ReLU(x)

        x = self.deConv3x304(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        return(x)
```

I believe its happening when I am trying to reshape the tensor into a 2D tensor (like image) from FC to deconv layer.

I have tried using reshape function, but the same problem persists. Im not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: I get this error when I run backward(). Here is the code snippet for that!

```
            optimizerVAE.zero_grad()
            variationalAE.train()

            vaeT = vaeT.to('cuda')

            mu, sigma, xHat, z = variationalAE(srcClrT)

            loss = vaeLoss(srcClrT, mu, sigma, xHat, z)

            loss.backward()
```

Edit 1: Added Code to my VAE loss.

```
class getVAELoss(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(getVAELoss, self).__init__()

def forward(self, x, mu, sigma, xHat, z):
    # Caluclate ELBO
    # ELBO = KLDivergence - reconstruction loss
    
    # Reconstruction loss 
    # Compute the probability of x uner n-d distribution
    logScale = nn.parameter.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.0]).to('cuda'))
    scale = torch.exp(logScale)
    dist = torch.distributions.Normal(xHat,scale)
    logProbXZ = dist.log_prob(x)
    logProbXZ = logProbXZ.sum(dim=(1,2,3))
    reconstructionLoss = logProbXZ

    # KL Divergence
    # create two probabilities p and q
    # P is the reference distribution with zero mean and unit sigma
    p = torch.distributions.Normal(torch.zeros_like(mu), torch.ones_like(sigma))
    q = torch.distributions.Normal(mu,sigma)

    # Calculating the log Probablility with the Z
    logQZX = q.log_prob(z)
    logPz = p.log_prob(z)

    KL = logQZX - logPz

    KL = KL.sum(-1)

    elbo = KL - reconstructionLoss

    elbo = elbo.mean()

    return(elbo)
```

The VAE loss is very similar to one shown in [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_yGmk8ahWhDs23U4mpplBFa-39fsEJoT)

**EDIT 2**
Looking at several VAE network architectures, I realized that only 1 FC is used in the decoder network, so removing the second FC layer and changing the size of the first FC, removed the error. But I don't understand why this is happening.

```
self.FC1 = nn.Linear(channels, 1024*4*13)

#self.FC2 = nn.Linear(channels, 10656)
```

Comment: Could you show `vaeLoss`? If think this is where the problem lies...

Comment: Hey @Ivan, I have added the VAE Loss.. I will also look at the vae loss to see If I can detect some problem!

Comment: Removing the second FC layer and changing the width of FC made the error go away! But I still don't understand why that happened!
Updated the post with this progress